# Are longer passwords more secure?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

There are more and more sites claiming that long passwords which are chained words are not only easier to remember, but also more secure then short but obscure ones.

Don't get me wrong: I totally get the idea of entropy, but are actual bruteforce-attacks really that stupid? With Markov-Chains and dictionaries isn't that misleading the user?

Sites claiming so are Drobbox and for example this xkcd-comic:

[image: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png]

Comment: We already had this here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase

Comment: Thanks didn't find that ***marking as duplicate***